# Error while rendering partial in layouts folder

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to factor out some code from my application layout into a partial. So I have this in my layouts/application.html.erb file:

```
<%= render 'layouts/my_links_create' %>
```

and I have  `_my_links_create.html.erb` file with some link_to's in my `views/layouts directory`. But I am getting the error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in Pages#home...
Missing partial layouts/_my_links_create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html]
Searched in: * "/home/adminuser/Documents/homedir/myappdir/app/views"
```

I am using partials at so many places in my app. Can't figure out why this is not working?

Comment: Are you sure you have `_my_links_create.html.erb` under `/app/views/layouts`?

Comment: Yes it is there. I am using bootrstrap and datatables for layout. Can they cause this?

Comment: Upon checking minutely I discovered that I had created the file in another version of my app. Moved the file to correct app and it works. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking minutely I discovered that I had created the file in another version of my app. Moved the file to correct app and it works. Sorry for the trouble.